# Search two field values using CJuiAutoComplete

Tags: yii, autocomplete

I want to search two fields namely,name and tags using cJuiautocomplete, how to perform this task ??

My CJuiAutoComplete code:

```
<?php   $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name'=>'test1',
    'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'name',
    //'attribute'=>'tags',
    'value'=>'',
    'source'=>$this->createUrl('campaign/autocompleteTest'),
    'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'fold',
            'select'=>' function(event,ui) { this.value=ui.item.value; ',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array( 'class' => 'input-xx search-query'),
   ));?>
```

My Controller code:

```
public function actionAutocompleteTest() {
    $res =array();
    $res2 =array();
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {

        $qtxt ="SELECT name FROM crm_campaign WHERE name LIKE :name";
        $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
        $command->bindValue(":name", '%'.$_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $res =$command->queryColumn();
        $tagsql ="SELECT tags FROM crm_campaign WHERE tags LIKE :name";
        $tagcommand =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($tagsql);
        $tagcommand->bindValue(":name", '%'.$_GET['term'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $tag =$tagcommand->queryColumn();
        foreach ($tag as $t)
        {
            $res2 = explode(',',$t);
        }

    }

    echo CJSON::encode(array_merge($res,$res2));
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

can anyone put me in the right path??

Comment: tag is another text box? or having some static values?

Comment: like name tag is another attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can do with js option:

```
'source'=>'js: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "'.$this->createUrl('campaign/autocompleteTest').'",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            term: request.term,
            tag: $("#tag_id").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
                response(data);
        }
    })
 }',
```

**Edit:**

```
foreach ($tag as $t)
        {
            $res2 = explode(',',$t);
            $res = array_merge($res,$res2);
        }
```

Comment: actually the above code of mine works for name but tags data was not filtered,i have only one autocomplete field,i want to use that widget to search to attribute values(name,tags)...i think your code owrks for tag filter only... how to filter both name and tags??? what is tag_id???

Comment: tag_id is tags textbox id. I just added client side script. You have to do filter code in server side.

Comment: i dont have textbox for tags,only one CuiAutocomplete box

Comment: then you are going to search in both name and tag? This is related with your logic. Not with CJuiAutoComplete.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting from controller?

Comment: only name data is filtering,tags data not filtering...i mentioned attribute in cjuiautocomplete as name only,so name only filtering i think!!! how to filter two attributes